# PHP html generator class

Tags: php, html, class, foreach

i use this class for create HTML content

```
http://code.google.com/p/php-class-html-generator/
```

I try to build a table in this way , but the html result is wrong...

```
$messalist = array(...);

    $html = htmltag::createElement('table')->id( $attr['id'] );

        foreach($messagelist as $message){
             $html->addElement('tr')
             ->addElement('td')->setText($message['subject'])
             ->addElement('td')->setText($message['from'])
             ->addElement('td')->setText($message['date'])
             ->addElement('td')->setText($message['size']);
        }

echo $html;
```

How do it in right way?
Thanks

This is generated html:

```
<table id="messagelist">
    <tr>
    <td>
    <td>
    <td>
    <td>1.91kB</td>23 Feb 11:56 AM</td>To: me@me.com</td>Re: helooo</td></tr>
    <tr>

    <td>
    <td>
    <td>
    <td>1.67kB</td>27 Feb 6:56 AM</td>me@me.com</td>Re: Helloo</td></tr></table>
```

and this is what i need:

```
<table id="messagelist">
    <tr>
    <td>1.91kB<td></td>23 Feb 11:56 AM</td><td>To: me@me.com</td><td>Re: helooo</td></tr>
    <tr>
    <td>1.67kB</td><td>27 Feb 6:56 AM</td><td>me@me.com</td><td>Re: Helloo</td></tr></table>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
foreach($messagelist as $message){
     $tr= $html->addElement('tr');
     $tr->addElement('td')->setText($message['subject']);
     $tr->addElement('td')->setText($message['from']);
     $tr->addElement('td')->setText($message['date']);
     $tr->addElement('td')->setText($message['size']);
}
```

Comment: @Ste So could you post what you expected and what you got? What is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Not too familiar with this generator, but you've only included a semi-colon after the last ->setText. Is that appropriate syntax? I've seen this type of shorthand before, but typically it requires your first to be a full declaration:

```
$html->addElement('td')->setText($message['subject'])
     ->addElement....
     ->addElement...
     ->addElement....;
```

Might be worth giving it a try.